# Long Term Experience with Dual-Boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dropbox

Currently, I am thinking about setting up a Dual-Boot Environment on my Thinkpad T410.

I have a 240GB SSD and a 500GB HDD (Ultrabay). I want to split the SSD and install Windows/Ubuntu. The 500GB HDD is shared storage (NTFS).

I want my Dropbox Folder and other Data Stuff to be shared on the HDD. I found an article that claims that the Dropbox thing works.
[Share Your Dropbox folder Between Windows and Linux Using a Data Partition](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/share-your-dropbox-folder-between-windows-and-linux-using-a-data-partition)

My question is:

- Do you have long-term experience with such a dual-boot setup and can recommend it?
- This setup will be my daily driver so it should be reliable. I had some bad experience with dual-boot so I wanted some confirmation that it will work reliable.
- Minor side question: I found threads that recommend putting the home folder on the shared drive. Are there any long term experiences with that?

**Edit:**
With long-term I mean at least 1-2 years and not just 2 weeks.
With reliable I mean that I don't want to fix some Grub stuff every 3 months. I want it to work after setting things up.

Comment: Define "long term", "reliable".

Comment: @muru Thanks for the comment. See my edit above.

Comment: 1. Yes and yes. 2. What sort for confirmation? 3. Bad idea if the shared partition is NTFS. Better to keep specific folders instead.

Comment: @muru Thanks again. 2. The sort you just gave me. Maybe a list of issues that may occur or something like that. Things to look out for that are not described in the major Tutorials, but people realize after using the system for some years. Depends on the experience as I am not sure if I really want to switch to dual-boot. 3. Though so, as well.

Comment: As for grub...It is usually Windows who is the culprit of destroying Grub...The trick is to find a way to not allow windows to install its own boot loader.You should be careful whenever installing a new version of Windows or installing a service pack.

Comment: Use GRUB but not Windows BOOTMGR as your primary boot manager. GRUB allows option manipulation at boot menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how to prevent this? What exactly can break here?

Comment: It really just deletes grub and puts its own stuff.Other than being careful with big updates I am not sure what to do.And every time you are installing Windows and Ubuntu,install Windows first,then Ubuntu.

Comment: That sounds like a bummer. Is this easily fixable?

Comment: @Robin the easy fix for Windows destroying your grub on an irregular and unpredictable basis is to install Windows on a Virtual Machine under Virtualbox. This approach has saved me numerous headaches over the past few years.

Comment: The solution is install windows first.  But if you didn't, you should just need to re-install grub after installing windows.  You may need to do this by booting into a Live CD/USB with a compatible version of grub and using `grub install <device>` or whatever the correct command is.

Comment: Windows doesn't "randomly" overwrite grub just from normal use.  It will do so when installing or attempting to install itself though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you have long-term experience with such a dual-boot setup and can recommend it?

Yes and yes. I started using Dropbox just after it started and have been using the same disk space for Windows and Ubuntu.

> This setup will be my daily driver so it should be reliable. I had some bad experience with dual-boot so I wanted some confirmation that it will work reliable.

It is reliable. Biggest problem with dual boot related problems tends to be the user. I have yet to face any problems with my dual boot. I started with Ubuntu 12.04LTS + Windows 7 and am now on Ubuntu 15.04 + the same Windows 7 where every 6 months my Ubuntu system is formatted and re-installed.

> Minor side question: I found threads that recommend putting the home folder on the shared drive. Are there any long term experiences with that?

I would vote against that. I would keep /home/$USER/ on the same partition as / (there is no need for an /home/ partition anymore). But symlink the directories to the shared directory.

---

My current setup: 120GB SSD, 1Tb HDD. SSD is split in Windows base (or C:) and / and the HDD holds all the data for both systems where 200Gb is `NTFS` and the rest `ext4`. I hardly use Windows 7 (mostly to program my remote :X )

Comment: OP is asking about Long term support of Ubuntu

Comment: "long-term experience" is not about LTS. The edit he made also makes be believe he means "usage". Besides that: I do not see any meaning in LTS for the OS itself in relation with this; the OS is the OS. No matter how long you use it (EOL is just something we on AU use to kill support; but that does not mean it actually ends).

Comment: ultimately OP has to stick to LTS stable release because he is already paranoid with dual-boot

Comment: I disagree with that. Using normal releases will make OP less paranoid.

Comment: @Mudit Personally, I think dual-boot is more fragile than the OS. At least that was my experience some years ago. So I wanted to revisit that topic.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for the brilliant answer. This makes me more confident going the dual-boot way.

Comment: Alternative: install Ubuntu and virtualbox in it and use a container to install Windows in it. My boss swears by it.